# I try to modify an Excel using Perl and Win32::Ole

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

I'm struggling with this and have red a lot of articles showing how it should work, but I have no success:

My system is a Windows 7 with Office 2016 installed and activated.
I want to use an Excel files as template modify it and save it to a new location. Here is my code:

```
sub ExcelWriter {
    my $Template = "../templates/template.xls";
    my $ExcelFile = $MyOutDir."New_Excel_File.xls";
    my $Excel = new Win32::OLE('Excel.Application');
    if (-f $Template) {
        my $WorkBook = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($Template);
        my $WorkSheet = $WorkBook->Worksheets('Overview');
        $WorkSheet->Cells(5,3)->{Value} = $Customer;
        $WorkBook->SaveAs($ExcelFile);
        $WorkBook->Close();
        undef $WorkBook;
        undef $Excel;
    }
}
```

I'm getting "`Can't call method "Worksheets" on an undefined value at...`"
When I use "`Workbooks->Add`" and "`Worksheets->Add`" to create a new Workbook I can write the cells. Even selecting Worksheets work here!

For the experts this seem to be obvious, but I must have missed something here. I already saved my Workbook from ".xlsx" to ".xls" and removed all formulas etc... and even create a new blank Workbook!

Thank you for your help

Regards
Laurent

Comment: I think I just found it out. The variable $Template uses "../" which gets redirected with the WIN32::OLE module to "....AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows"

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to (using the original ".xlsx" file):

```
sub ExcelWriter {
    my ($Volume, $Directory, $File) = File::Spec->splitpath(__FILE__);
    my $Template = $Volume.$Directory.'..\templates\template.xlsx';
    my $ExcelFile = $MyOutDir.'New_Excel_File.xlsx';
    my $Excel = new Win32::OLE('Excel.Application');
    my $WorkBook = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($Template);
    my $WorkSheet = $WorkBook->Worksheets('Overview');
    $WorkSheet->Cells(5,3)->{Value} = $Customer;
    $WorkBook->SaveAs($ExcelFile);
    $WorkBook->Close();
    undef $WorkBook;
    undef $Excel;
}
```

...and it works fine!